# Как обновлять виджет ВК через сервер?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте, виджет

Я получил токен для работы с виджетом в сообществе через vkminiapps и getCommunityToken, и теперь хочу обновлять виджет через Python скрипт, но чтобы выводилась информация о пользователе, например имя, вот пример кода виджета

```
var test = API.users.get()@.first_name;
    return {
    "title": "Заголовок виджета",
    "text": test[0],
    "descr": "Описание"
};
```

В виджете должен быть показано имя пользователя, который зашел на страницу
Далее делается запрос на метод appWidgets.update, с токеном и type = text, но выходит ошибка
`One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: text is empty`

То есть API просто возвращает пустой текст, то есть ничего не нашел, хотя если этот же самый код отправить на метод execute, то как раз таки и выводится информация о текущем пользователе.
Вопрос:
Как работают приложения, который обновляют виджеты? Или что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в общем, разобрался, надо было использовать Args.uid - айди пользователя, который зашел на страницу

```
var test = API.users.get({user_id: Args.uid})@.first_name;
    return {
    "title": "Заголовок виджета",
    "text": test[0],
    "descr": "Описание"
};
```